# Rails: before_action :authenticate_admin! doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm doing this in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :admins, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: {sessions: 'admins/sessions'}
devise_scope :admin do
  get "admins/home"=> "admins/sessions#home", :as => "admin_home"
end
```

But when I put the `before_action :authenticate_admin!` in the sessions controller and open the `admins/home` the login screen doesn't appear, no errors pop up neither. I get full access to the page without having to log in!

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
   before_action :authenticate_admin!

   def home
   end

   def new
     super
   end


   def create
     super
   end


   def destroy
     super
   end

   protected

   def configure_sign_in_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
   end
end
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste code in admins/sessions controller

Comment: Thanks for the reply @krishnar, I upload the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your defined route to create session in *home* action.So change home action**

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

   def home
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   end

   def new
     super
   end


   # override method here
  def create
  end


   def destroy
     super
   end

   protected

   def configure_sign_in_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
   end
end
```

NOTE: And put this in application controller

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!
```

Comment: I still get full access to the page without having to log in!! When I go the `admins/home` the login screen doesn't appear, no errors pop up neither! Also, I delete the `before_action :authenticate_admin!` from the `sessions_controller.rb`

Comment: @Theopap  before_action :authenticate_admin!     u should put this in application controller

Comment: I moved the  to the `application_controller.rb` but nothing has changed... I'm using` rubyMine` so this is the error it gives me only inside `RubyMine`: `Expected method name from current or parent classes up to 'ActionController::Base', but found ':authenticate_admin!'. or hash expected`

Comment: I just had to put the code inside the `def home` instead of the `def create` method, and delete the `before_action :authenticate_admin!` from the `application_controller`! Thanks for the help!!! Since you found 90% of the solution you can go ahead and answer the question and I'll accept.

Comment: @Theopap  ok now I see you have changed session route itself.Its hitting to home action. sorry.

Comment: @Theopap I updated code. Accept answer and upvote if my solution was helpful